# NSPopUpButton subclass attributedTitle

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, appkit

I'm facing some confusion with how I'm subclassing `NSPopUpButton`, namely that I can't set the `attributedTitle` like on a button (to get a custom font, color, and baseline offset).

The following code has no effect:

```
class CustomPopUpButton: NSPopUpButton {
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        self.wantsLayer = true
        self.layerContentsRedrawPolicy = .OnSetNeedsDisplay

        self.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: self.title, attributes: [
            NSFontAttributeName: NSFont(name: "Impact", size: 15)!,
            NSForegroundColorAttributeName: NSColor(calibratedRed: 0.2, green: 0.270588235, blue: 0.031372549, alpha: 1),
            NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName: 2
        ])
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Willeke pointed out, I needed to set the attributed string on the menu item itself.  I wanted to just set it on the button and let the menu items not display in the same font, but I settled on being okay with it.

I looped through the items in the menu on initialization and set the style on each item, then re-did that after adding items.

Here's the final code for my `NSPopUpButton` subclass with `NSAttributedString`s:

```
class CustomPopUpButton: NSPopUpButton {
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)

        setItemStyles()
    }

    override func addItemsWithTitles(itemTitles: [String]) {
        super.addItemsWithTitles(itemTitles)

        setItemStyles()
    }

    private func setItemStyles() {
        for item in self.itemArray {
            item.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: item.title, attributes: [
                NSFontAttributeName: NSFont(name: "Impact", size: 15)!,
                NSForegroundColorAttributeName: NSColor(calibratedRed: 0.2, green: 0.270588235, blue: 0.031372549, alpha: 1),
                NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName: 2
            ])
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

NSPopUpButton displays the selected menu item. When you set the attributed string of the menu item, the popup button will display an attributed title.

Answer (score 1):

When taking a look at the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSPopUpButton_Class/), you will see that `NSPopUpButton` only works with strings.

The `attributedTitle` property only refers to its superclass `NSButton` and is therefore not represented by `NSPopUpButton` itself. 
To set a standard title however, you can use the `setTitle` method.

From the docs:

> If the receiver displays a pop-up menu, this method changes the current item to be the item with the specified title, adding a new item by that name if one does not already exist.

Comment: Hmm... Then how does one change the font, color, size, etc. of the button portion of an `NSPopUpButton`?  Yes, the documentation for `setTitle` says it only takes a string, which makes sense, but that doesn't say to me that there's no way to set an `attributedTitle` on it, especially given it's a subclass of `NSButton`.